# How to insert a character to a text control in wxwidgets from the code itself?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, textctrl

I have this textctrl

```
FTextCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(parent, wxID_ANY, _("Text"), wxPoint(20, 20), wxDefaultSize, wxTE_CENTRE | wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_TC"));
```

For this control based on the programming logic, I want to insert a editable character into the text field. How can we do the same?

Comment: check the documentation for wxTextCtrl. It has 2 functions that will do the job - one that will send an event and one that will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert text at the given position, you should use `SetSelection()` to set the insertion point (by creating an empty selection at the desired position) and then `WriteText()`. Of course, if you just want to append the text, you could use `AppendText()` directly.

Finally, you may decide to just use `ChangeValue()` to replace the entire value instead of fiddling with these functions.